# How long would it take a human to reach Tau Ceti (11.89 LY) safely?

Tags: general-relativity

Safely meaning they wouldn't have to feel a G force over 2Gs.
Assuming we had technology to reach any feasible speed under light speed.
Also, how long would it be relative to Earth?

Comment: A basic calculation is possible using [these equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_travel_using_constant_acceleration#Interstellar_travel).  Note that how long depends on whether you mean from the traveler's point of view or Earth's - time dilation.

Comment: Getting rid of G-force using e.g. strong magnetic fields perhaps also involving implanting magnetic materials in the body seems to be technologically trivial compared to the challenges of interstellar space travel. Such a technology could also allow for a spacecrafts to make a hard 100 G landing without the astronauts getting injured.

Comment: Also http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109776/how-long-would-it-take-me-to-travel-to-a-distant-star?noredirect=1&lq=1